# How to use {} in Emmet?

Tags: emmet

today I was created a nav-bar and I would use `{}` in Emmet, I've used:

```
div.container>main>div.header>section.top-area>nav>ul>li*4>a{Home, Contact, About, Other}
```

I would that it become:

```
  <div class="container">
  <main>
    <div class="header">
      <section class="top-area">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Other</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </section>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

But my emmet-code become:

```
  <div class="container">
      <main>
        <div class="header">
          <section class="top-area">
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home, Contact, About, Other</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home, Contact, About, Other</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home, Contact, About, Other</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Home, Contact, About, Other</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </section>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
```

How to I use an option like my first code?

Comment: I've come across this feature and didn't find how to do it. My workaround is to put some flag (like SECTIONLABEL) and then search and replace it.

Comment: Yeah I think it only supports numbering with `*`. You can always do `div.container>main>div.header>section.top-area>nav>ul>li>a{Home}^li>a{Contact}^li>a{About}^li>a{Other}`, or create a custom snippet that will tab through each place for you to type.

Answer (score 0):

First, write the text items of the list, line by line:

```
Home
Contact
About
Other
```

Then select all items, and ***Wrap with Abbreviation*** – Ctrl+Shift+A (Adobe Brackets) or Ctrl+Shift+G (Sublime Text);

Finally write the code to expand:

```
div.container>main>div.header>section.top-area>nav>ul>li*>a{$#}
```

`*` — reproduces to as many list elements as the lines in the selected text;

`{$#}` — each line is placed in the element's text content.

More about this Emmet feature → http://docs.emmet.io/actions/wrap-with-abbreviation/#wrapping-individual-lines

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the anchors in the list items separately. This will work.

```
div.container>main>div.header>section.top-area>nav>ul>li>a[href=""]{Home}
+li>a[href=""]{Contac}+li>a[href=""]{About}+li>a[href=""]{Other}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu*12>nav>ul>li>a[href="#" alt="menu"]{bomb}^li>a[href="#" alt="menu"]{food}^li>a[href="#" alt="menu"]{bugs}^li>a[href="#" alt="menu"]{beer}
```

This works for me, just use your menu names